# Recreate Windows Look-and-Feel border of JFrame or JDialog?

Tags: java, windows, swing, look-and-feel

I need to recreate the translucent border of `JFrame` or `JDialog` that appears when setting the windows look and feel in swing.

I need it because Windows LaF does not let you access the title bar (on the border). In fact, I need to apply a `MouseAdapter` to the `JDialog` that gets notified when it is dragged/pressed/released. In windows laf, as you cannot get access to the bar component,  you can only apply a `ComponentListener` which gives you notification only when moving (so you don't capture anything when the user has grabbed it but hasn't moved yet, or either when the user "releases" it).

Therefore, I decided to go with undecorated dialogs and apply the listeners to my custom bar. However I want the custom dialog looks exactly as in windows laf (it means I need to recreate the border).

I'm not very experienced in Graphics2D to override the `paintBorder()` method, so I'm asking for your help.

Has anyone ever faced this problem and has a tested solution?

Answer (score 1):

> As of the Java Platform, Standard Edition 6 (Java SE 6) Update 10 release, you can add translucent and shaped windows to your Swing applications.

This means that you can have your `JFrame` emulate a native window with the rounded corners and transparency.

In your case, your approach would be in the `JFrame` level instead of the border level because the border is painted on top of the `JFrame` (or `JDialog`, for that matter). Therefore, if the `JFrame` is not already rounded, for instance, the `paintBorder()` method will still be painting on top of a rectangular area of the screen.

Check this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) from Oracle covering shaped and translucent `JFrame`.